# Realloc memory to array

Tags: c, realloc

So I am writing a c program that reads the contents of a text file with integers inside, each integer is on a new line. I want to create an array to then copy the contents of the text file into the array. Then I have another text file similar to the first one but slightly shorter, I want to reallocate memory to the array by counting the number of lines in the second file and then eventually copying the contents of the second text file into the same array.

I have gotten to the point of reallocating memory to the array but it doesn't work, I have tried numerous different ways but can't seem to get my head around it.

**Main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void){

    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;
    int number, temp, i=0, j;
    int numLines=0;

    fp1 = fopen("numbers1.txt", "r");
    while((number = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF){
        if(number == '\n'){
            numLines++;
        }
    }
    rewind(fp1);

    int *numbersFromFile;
    numbersFromFile = (int*) calloc(numLines, sizeof (int));

    while((number = fgetc(fp1)) !=EOF){
        fscanf(fp1, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i]);
        i++;
    }

    temp = numLines;

    numLines=0;

    fp2 = fopen("numbers2.txt", "r");
    while((number = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF){
        if(number == '\n'){
            numLines++;
        }
    }

    (int*) realloc(numbersFromFile, numLines);

    rewind(fp2);

    while((number = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF){
        fscanf(fp2, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i]);
        i++;
    }

    numLines += temp;
    for(i=0; i<numLines; i++){
        printf("%d\n", numbersFromFile[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: `realloc` **returns** the realloc'ed memory. You're not grabbing a hold of it. Why are you even casting it then?

Comment: @DeiDei then how do I assign it to the existing array?

Comment: Well, you don't have arrays anywhere, you have a pointer. Just reassign, your initial pointer is invalid after you call `realloc` anyway. `existing_ptr = realloc(...);`

Comment: 1) `while((number = fgetc(fp1)) !=EOF){
        fscanf(fp1, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i]);` --> `while(1 == fscanf(fp1, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i])){`

Comment: 2) `(int*) realloc(numbersFromFile, numLines);` --> `numbersFromFile =  realloc(numbersFromFile, (temp + numLines)*sizeof(int));`

Comment: @DeiDei yeah I tried to do that before, but when the program reads from the second file and tries to copy the contents it crashes

Comment: Also check the return value from `fopen`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thank you, I forgot about the addition of temp and numLines, that has solved it

Comment: when calling `realloc()`, always place the returned value into a temporary pointer, then check that pointer for (!=NULL)  If not NULL, then assign to the target pointer.  Otherwise, when `realloc()` fails, the pointer to the original allocated heap memory is lost.  That results in a memory leak.

Comment: when calling any of the heap allocation functions (malloc, calloc, realloc) 1) do not cast the returned value.  The returned value has type `void*` so can be assigned to any other pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: the last line in a text file might not end with a '\n' sequence, so need to track if somewhere in a line, when at the end, and if so, then add 1 more tot he line count. (in the current scenario, always adding one more would be ok.

Comment: this kind of loop: `while((number = fgetc(fp2)) != EOF){
        fscanf(fp2, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i]);
        i++;
    }`  will not work as the leading char from each line could be lost and the last line might not be input or might try to read a number past the end of the file.  Suggest; `while(  1 == fscanf(fp2, "%d", &numbersFromFile[i]) ) { i++; }`
    }

Comment: a lot of processing time is being wasted counting the number of lines.  A much better approach would be to perform an initial allocation of (say) 256 integers, then keep track of how many are filled with values and when that array is full, then realloc twice as many integers.  Continue this sequence until all the integers are read.   Note: having some left over allocated space when done reading finished reading all the integers is acceptable.  NOTE: be sure to pass the pointer to the allocated memory to `free()` before exiting the program.

Comment: Before exiting the program, close the files by: `fclose( fp1 ); fclose( fp2 );`